# Using async/await to get data from a callback and return a value only after a promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to use async/await but I think I'm misunderstanding something critically.

As basically as possible, I am trying to calculate the distance between a list of locations and one designated location using google maps api.

Here is a rough example of what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/qu5y69rj/1/

You can see that the result of that function is `undefined` 3 times instead of what I would expect which would be `{distance: "ZERO_RESULTS"}` for each call in the case of my contrived example.

```
getDistance = async (start, end) => {
  const origin = new google.maps.LatLng(start[0], start[1]);
  const final = new google.maps.LatLng(end[0], end[1]);
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  let result; //need to return this value!
  await service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [origin],
      destinations: [final],
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, (response, status) => {
      if(status === 'OK') result = {distance: response.rows[0].elements[0].status}
    }
  )
  return result;
}
```

Why is result being returned before the promise is resolved? How can I return the value of `result` only after that promise is resolved? It is my understanding that by telling javascript to await, I'm saying don't move forward until this promise has resolved. Is that incorrect? I'm pretty confused and this has me pulling my hair out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: async/await just wraps promises. I don't see any promises in this code. Is `service.getDistanceMatrix` your code? Can you make it return a promise rather than take a callback?

Comment: no it's part of the google maps api so it is what it is

Comment: You cannot `await` a callback-style asynchronous function. You should first learn [how to use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) before trying to tackle [`async` / `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `service.getDistanceMatrix` accepts a callback which means ti most likely doesn't return a promise.

However, async functions expect promises.

As a fix, you can wrap `getDistanceMatrix` it in a promise (or use another method that does return a promise):

```
const getDistanceMatrix = (service, data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  service.getDistanceMatrix(data, (response, status) => {
    if(status === 'OK') {
      resolve(response)
    } else {
      reject(response);
    }
  })
});

getDistance = async (start, end) => {
  const origin = new google.maps.LatLng(start[0], start[1]);
  const final = new google.maps.LatLng(end[0], end[1]);
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  const result = await getDistanceMatrix(
    service,
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [final],
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }
  )
  return {
    distance: result.rows[0].elements[0].status
  };
};
```

Comment: awesome this works like a charm! so just so I'm clear on this, I can all call `await` on promises in a function I declare as `async`? and calling `await` does "pause" the code until the promise is resolved/rejected?

Comment: Thanks! slick implementation

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to do async operations with JavaScript:

1. **Callbacks**: A function accepts a callback as its final argument. It returns nothing (`undefined`), and when the async operation completes, the callback is called.
2. **Promises**: A function returns a promise, which resolves to the result of the async operation when it completes.
3. **Async/Await**: A function returns a promise, and can use the `async` keyword to get the values of async operations inside its definition. Whatever is returned using the `return` keyword will be wrapped in a promise.

Since `getDistanceMatrix` accepts a callback, it returns nothing. The `await` keyword as used in the code doesn't need to wait; it immediately gets the `undefined` value returned by `getDistanceMatrix`. When the operation completes and the callback is called, the `getDistance` has long finished executing and returned.

You need to wrap `getDistanceMatrix` so it returns a promise, make `getAllDistance()` return a promise as well, and await that promise in your `console.log()` statement:

```
const coords = [
  ['-36.22967', '-125.80271'],
  ['54.06395', '54.06395'],
  ['-5.00263', '-137.92806']
];

function getDistance (start, end) {
  const origin = new google.maps.LatLng(start[0], start[1]);
  const final = new google.maps.LatLng(end[0], end[1]);
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [origin],
      destinations: [final],
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, (response, status) => {
      if(status === 'OK') {
        resolve({ distance: response.rows[0].elements[0].status });
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Not OK'));
      }
    }
  );
  });
}

function getAllDistance (starts, end) {
  const promisedDistances = starts.map((start) => getDistance(start, end));
  // Promise.all turns an array of promises into a promise
  // that resolves to an array.
  return Promise.all(promisedDistances);
}

getAllDistance(coords, ['-30.23978', '-161.31203'])
  .then(result => { console.log(result); });
```